# Python process takes a very long time to interrupt

Tags: python, cpu-usage, keyboardinterrupt

I'm running a particularly CPU expensive script that requires a lot of my CPU. I let it run for an hour or so and interrupt it at some point. When I interrupt it, however, it doesn't actually stop the process. When I check if the process is still running with ps a, it lists the process with "U+".

I can see that + means "running in the foreground" but don't know what U stands for.

Is this due to a memory leak or something? What is the explanation for it taking so long to interrupt the process?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "interrupt" ? Do you press `ctrl-c` ? Is it in a python prompt or reunning via file ?

Comment: @ygorg Yes, using ctrl-c

Comment: @tryingtolearn Try putting this at the top of your script: `import signal; signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)`. This should allow you to terminate the script with ctrl+c. I'm not sure what the "U" stands for - "unresponsive", maybe, or "unknown"? What platform are you running this on?

Comment: I'm running this on a Mac. I'll add that command and give this a try.